# Unity Webgl game centered in webpage

Tags: html, unity-game-engine, html5-canvas

I have built a WebGL game using Unity, and I put it on a domaine, everything is working fine, but I want to center the game screen in the webpage like in [thisimage.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DohGj.png)

here is the index.html code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Game Title</title>
    <script src="Build/UnityLoader.js"></script>
    <script>
      var gameInstance = UnityLoader.instantiate("gameContainer", "Build/WebGL.json");
    </script>

  </head>
  <body style="background-color:black;">
    <div id="gameContainer" style="width: 1024px; height: 576px; margin: auto "></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Doesn’t look like you have tried to center it at all. What have you looked at doing ?

Comment: This sounds like a pure `CSS` related question .. the only tag you didn't add ^^ Also: It is centered for me: https://imgur.com/j9AbD0K (just gave the `div` a background color)

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer for this i just added a this style to head

```
<style>
.container {
width: 80%;
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 20px;
}
</style>
```

and I put the div gameContainer inside another div with the style above. Not sure if this is the right solution, but it works

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar issue, my WebGL build was suddenly left aligned. Found out that I mistakenly changed the WebGL template setting on Player Settings from Default to Minimal. Default is centered aligned.